# Flutter: Is there a way to block a FixedExtentScrollController from going past a certain index?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Basically what the title says, I want to dynamically block the scrollcontroller from going past a certain index, as to not make a time interval that's negative:

I don't want the right time to be earlier than the left time.

[image]

Here is some basic code that I used to create these two time pickers:

```
Widget durationPicker(bool inHour, FixedExtentScrollController _controller) {
  return Builder(
    builder: (context) {
      return CupertinoPicker(
        scrollController: _controller,
        magnification: 1.1,
        children: List.generate(
          inHour ? 24 : 12,
          (index) => Container(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: Builder(
              builder: (context) {
                return Text(
                  inHour ? '$index' : '${index * 5}',
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
        ),
        itemExtent: 40,
        onSelectedItemChanged: (int value) {},
      );
    },
  );
}

class CupertinoDoubleTimePicker extends StatelessWidget {
  CupertinoDoubleTimePicker({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  final FixedExtentScrollController _hourScrollControllerStart =
      FixedExtentScrollController();
  final FixedExtentScrollController _minuteControllerStart =
      FixedExtentScrollController();
  final FixedExtentScrollController _hourScrollControllerEnd =
      FixedExtentScrollController();
  final FixedExtentScrollController _minuteControllerEnd =
      FixedExtentScrollController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
      children: [
        SizedBox(
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.3,
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.2,
          child: Row(
            children: [
              Expanded(child: durationPicker(true, _hourScrollControllerStart)),
              const Text(':'),
              Expanded(child: durationPicker(true, _minuteControllerStart)),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        SizedBox(
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.3,
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.2,
          child: Row(
            children: [
              Expanded(child: durationPicker(true, _hourScrollControllerEnd)),
              const Text(':'),
              Expanded(child: durationPicker(true, _minuteControllerEnd)),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: share your code first

Comment: I just added the code

Answer (score 0):

I found a working solution, although from a UI standpoint not a clean one.

if one adds a listener to each scrollcontroler, one can simply just make it jump back every time that _controller1.selectedItem is bigger / smaller than _controller2.selectedItem. But this looks really choppy in the UI and doesn't 'deactivate' all invalid values, it just ensures you can't select them

the code looks like this:

```
and one could just do this for every of the 4 controllers
 _hourScrollControllerEnd.addListener(() {
      if (_hourScrollControllerEnd.selectedItem <
          _hourScrollControllerStart.selectedItem) {
        _hourScrollControllerEnd.jumpTo(_hourScrollControllerStart.offset);
      }
    });
```